# Jsp parameters scop

Tags: jsp

What is the difference between 
request.sendRedirect()

and

requestDispatcher.forward()

in terms of request parameters?

Comment: this one is a Duplicate already answered  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629152/sendredirect-or-request-dispatch-is-more-efficient  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward

```
* a forward is performed internally by the servlet
* the browser is completely unaware that it has taken place, so its original URL remains intact
* any browser reload of the resulting page will simple repeat the original request, with the original URL
```

Redirect

```
* a redirect is a two step process, where the web application instructs the browser to fetch a second URL, which differs from the original
* a browser reload of the second URL will not repeat the original request, but will rather fetch the second URL
* redirect is marginally slower than a forward, since it requires two browser requests, not one
* objects placed in the original request scope are not available to the second request
```

see [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181)